# Publish IOS App to Appstore with SSID ( wifi) discovery/connect through app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I was trying to get a specific info before a IOS App development task which I searched but couldn't find anything relevant.

Wanted to know whether this requirement restricts (non compliance issue as per publish guidelines) the app to be published in App Store with features as below

- User scans and lists all available wifi connections in a tableview
- Selects one of the Wifi connection and connects on button click
- Stores the password and SSID for future connections.

Would there be any compliance issue related to the same functionalities when submitting to IOS app store. One of my colleague have advised me about the same but not able to explain why? Which I tried to find out searching the internet, but too specific to find anything relevant. Deeply appreciate an Expert advise on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything in the **Review Guidelines** that would object your app idea: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines

A couple of areas where you should have a more detailed look:

- 2.5.1 Apps may only use public APIs.
- 2.5.9 Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, or other native user
  interface elements or behaviors will be rejected.
- 5.1 Privacy

Technically, I'm not sure if it's even possible to change the WIFI not via the settings app, so I'd have a look their first. (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/is-there-an-ipod-app-to-easily-switch-wifi-on-and-off)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable thoughts. Stumbled upon the scenario where there is a machinery plant were each equipment has wifi Dongle to connect to a specific mobile client app to operate. So the process needs to connect to a SSID by filtering different SSIDs ( different equipments with Dongles) with Unique SSID names. Each equipment has different set of threshold readings which the app controls and sets alarms. This was developed in Android version without any hassles but in IOS couldn't find anything other than captivenetworksupport.Would be really helpful if this feature is there helps pairing

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe I've ever seen an app or a way to change SSID outside the Settings app. I explored a way to detect network changes, connects, disconnects, which work fine while the app is running. I was never able to influence how the user connected, just that a change happened. It also falls apart pretty quickly when the user backgrounds the app. Trying to keep a background task open long enough to poll the current connection fails pretty fast.

I wish Apple would provide some system level notification of Wifi connect events. This could be very useful to developers that want a little more control than Background App Refresh events.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. We have done the Android Version without any issue, but the IOS version seems to be having helpful classes for this apart from CNCapture . The requirement is such there is a Wifi Dongle connected with an Sensor Equipment which emits few values and should be paired with this device only. And from this mobile client the Users ( employees who manage the particular Machinery) . So they want to store the app to connect to specific WiFi Dongles out of multiple for specific equipments which they remotely operate.